# How to avoid code duplication in companion objects of subclasses

Tags: scala

I have the following pattern in my Scala code:

```
class A(x: Int)
object A {
  def apply(x: Int, y: Int) = new A(x + y)
}

class B(x: Int) extends A(x)
object B {
  def apply(x: Int, y: Int) = new B(x + y)
}
```

The apply methods are exactly the same, except for the Class of the object that they construct. I would like to avoid this code duplication, especially because in my real code I have several apply methods and they are much longer.

How can I achieve this? How can I remove this code duplication?

I thought about something like this:

```
class A(x: Int)
class B(x: Int) extends A(x)

trait C[T <: A] {
  def apply(x: Int, y: Int) = new T(x + y)
}

object A extends C[A]
object B extends C[B]
```

It doesn't work, because T is not a class and therefore I cannot do "new T(x + y)".

Comment: You can't really abstract over constructors. If you're willing to make `A` and `B` be `case class`es, you can call the (generated) `apply` method *of the companion object* in `C`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose this solution:

```
class A(x: Int)
class B(x: Int) extends A(x)

trait C[+T <: A] {
  def apply(x: Int, y: Int) = create(x + y)
  protected def create(x: Int): T
}

object A extends C[A] {
  override protected def create(x: Int) = new A(x)
}
object B extends C[B] {
  override protected def create(x: Int) = new B(x)
}
```

Take a look at `GenericCompanion` class. It is part of Scala collections library and may inspire you:
http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.generic.GenericCompanion

Comment: that really doesn't solve code duplication, does it?

Comment: it avoids duplication of "x + y", which is the only duplicated logic

Answer (score 3):

In the specific case you can do something like

```
class A(x: Int) {
  def this(x: Int, y: Int) = this(x + y)
}
class B(x: Int) extends A(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class Adder[T](f: Int => T) {
  def apply(x: Int, y: Int) = f(x + y)
}

class A(x: Int)
object A extends Adder(new A(_))

class B(x: Int) extends A(x)
object B extends Adder(new B(_))
```